# read wall post of some Facebook page and display in google app engine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do is read wall post of one Facebook page and display it as normal website hosted on Google app engine.

My main idea was to use Facebook API but it looks like its not possible. So my question is, it is possible to do so using the Facebook API itself? Or do I have to use some other script?

What if I want to use my Facebook ID instead of asking user to log in to Facebook. So that even if an user doesn't have Facebook account s/he can see the post on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to import a user's feed (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ ) if you have a `read_stream` permission. You should use the field `feed` of a `User`.

For example, you can use OAuth ([Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) is a good libraty which works on Google App Engine / Java), ask a user to connect to Facebook with `read_stream` permission, retrieve its feed and display it as you would for a "normal website".

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want to retrieve the posts of a "Facebook Page". Here you have two options:

1. Retrieving "**Public**" posts: this doesn't need any authorization/authentication; you just need to query something like:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/coca-cola/feed
   ```

   This would retrieve the public posts of the Coca Cola Facebook page. Also you can use the page id.
   P.S: No application needed!
2. Retrieving **All** posts (public/private): here I guess you need to get an admin of the page to add your application to get all the posts.

**UPDATE:**
As of June 3rd, even public posts require an access token. See: [developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509)
Thanks nikc!

Comment: As of June 3rd, even public posts require an access token. See: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509